# error[E0282]: type annotations needed

Tags: error, rust, polkadot, substrate

While I was building a subsrate node using `cargo build` I got this error message.

[[image: error[E0282]:type annotations needed1]

How to solve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rustup toolchain install nightly-2020-08-23
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly-2020-08-23
Then compile your node with this:
cargo +nightly-2020-08-23 build --release
```

Fixed it with this code.